# Creating a 3D line feature based on 3D point features

Tags: arcgis-10.0, point, 3d, line, 3d-analyst

In ArcGIS for Desktop 10.0, is it possible to create a 3D line feature by drawing a line that connects 3D point features?

Comment: Which Version of ArcGIS? - if an older version supporting VBA then there is some code here http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1741&t=188997#560065

Comment: The version of ArcGIS is 10.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I have not tested it.

3D Snapping in ArcGIS, which is available in ArcGlobe and ArcScene, and requires a 3D Analyst license, is described **[here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00q8000000z1000000)**.

Answer (score 0):

With 3d analyst, and other extensions you can open a globe and start an edit session.
I have not tested 3d snapping but have read that it can be done in that environment.

Comment: Does this need to be done in ArcScene?